# Is 'if q and r:' evaluated separately?

Tags: python

It's a very simple question. Is

```
if q and r:
```

always guaranteed to be equivalent to this?

```
if q:
  if r:
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python's `and` and `or` are **short-circuiting** operators, so yes: in your example, if "q" is false, then the interpreter will not evaluate "r".

*edit* — after a little thought it occurs to me that it's important to note that Python's `and` and `or` work kind-of like Javascript `&&` and `||`. They do not produce a boolean result.  In other words, the operands ("q" and "r") when evaluated are sort-of "internally" cast to boolean, but that's just to see how execution should proceed.  Thus, if "q" and "r" are both non-empty strings, the result of `q and r` is the string value of "r", not boolean `true`.  However, when used in the context given (an `if` statement), the `if` statement itself is going to cast the result to boolean in order to make its own control flow decision, so the answer for this example is still "yes" :-)

Comment: +1 for the edit of the boolean operators not actually returning a boolean.